# Jenkins JNLP remoting - Frequent ping timeouts

Tags: jenkins, timeout, ping, jnlp, agent

Jenkins agent has been connected to the master via JNLP remoting.

Initially, the connection seems to be successful for about 20 min, later ping was attempted thrice which fails, followed by successful reconnection of the agent. Thereby, incurs a downtime of 30 min approx.

```
Aug 30, 2021 7:12:32 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Aug 30, 2021 7:12:32 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkinsmain.cloud:9000
Aug 30, 2021 7:12:32 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect
Aug 30, 2021 7:12:32 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Remote identity confirmed: xx:d9:de:d9:xx.xx.xx.xx:b3
Aug 30, 2021 7:12:32 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
Aug 30, 2021 7:31:32 PM hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger$1 onDead
INFO: Ping failed. Terminating the channel JNLP4-connect connection to jenkinsmain.cloud/xx.xx.101.4:9000.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Ping started at 1630351652299 hasn't completed by 1630351892300
        at hudson.remoting.PingThread.ping(PingThread.java:133)
        at hudson.remoting.PingThread.run(PingThread.java:89)

Aug 30, 2021 7:36:32 PM hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger$1 onDead
INFO: Ping failed. Terminating the channel JNLP4-connect connection to jenkinsmain.cloud/xx.xx.101.4:9000.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Ping started at 1630351952301 hasn't completed by 1630352192302
        at hudson.remoting.PingThread.ping(PingThread.java:133)
        at hudson.remoting.PingThread.run(PingThread.java:89)

Aug 30, 2021 7:41:32 PM hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger$1 onDead
INFO: Ping failed. Terminating the channel JNLP4-connect connection to jenkinsmain.cloud/xx.xx.101.4:9000.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Ping started at 1630352252300 hasn't completed by 1630352492301
        at hudson.remoting.PingThread.ping(PingThread.java:133)
        at hudson.remoting.PingThread.run(PingThread.java:89)

Aug 30, 2021 7:43:01 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
Aug 30, 2021 7:43:11 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Performing onReconnect operation.
Aug 30, 2021 7:43:11 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: onReconnect operation failed.
Aug 30, 2021 7:43:11 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [https://jenkinsmain.cloud/]
Aug 30, 2021 7:43:11 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping]
Aug 30, 2021 7:43:11 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: jenkinsmain.cloud
  Agent port:    9000
  Identity:      xx:d9:de:d9:xx.xx.xx.xx:b3
Aug 30, 2021 7:43:11 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Aug 30, 2021 7:43:11 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to jenkinsmain.cloud:9000
Aug 30, 2021 7:43:11 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect
Aug 30, 2021 7:43:11 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Remote identity confirmed: xx:d9:de:d9:xx.xx.xx.xx:b3    
Aug 30, 2021 7:43:11 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more info to get an answer: what OS your using, are you using the Agent via Docker, what version of the Agent your using?

Comment: We are using Azure Cloud to host our servers.

Jenkins Master -( RHEL Server 7.7 + openjdk version "1.8.0_242")

Jenkins Slave - (RHEL Server 7.8 + java version "1.8.0_251" )

During the ping failures, when I manually ping to port 9000 is successful.

Comment: Jenkins ver. 2.222.1 is used on both the Jenkins servers. Basically, I am trying to connect an agent(which is also a master in the 'A' region) to a master of the 'B' region. We have separate azure subscriptions for each region.